# Add path to a zipped file name

Tags: powershell, zip

I need to add the location of the file to its name.
Like this: `C\user\someuser\folder\folder_logs`

And the name of the zipped file should be "2019_Jan_folder_logs".

I got it working until the date, can't add the name.

```
    $Zip = $target_path + "" + "{0:yyyy}_{0:MMM}" -f $_.LastWriteTime
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2 $Zip $_.FullName | Out-Null
    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
        Remove-Item $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your desired zip name, you only want the last part of the path included in the name.
If the current file `$_` has a LastWriteTime of April 1st 2019 for instance, this

```
$targetpath = 'C:\user\someuser\folder\folder_logs'
$Zip = '{0:yyyy_MMM}_{1}' -f $_.LastWriteTime, (Split-Path -Path $targetpath -Leaf)
```

will result in

```
2019_Apr_folder_logs
```

However, in your code block, you reverse the order and put the $targetpath in front of the new name.
Doing that here too:

```
$Zip = '{0}_{1:yyyy_MMM}' -f (Split-Path -Path $targetpath -Leaf), $_.LastWriteTime
```

results in:

```
folder_logs_2019_Apr
```

You can of course also append the actual file name `$_.BaseName` to that if you need to.